# Does table design belong on dba?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

Here's a typical question currently live on SO: [Is this database properly in 3NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689859/is-this-database-properly-in-3nf). The title pretty well sums up its content.

To me, this is a no-brainer to migrate to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Am I correct that it should go there?
Or is it on-topic for SO?

I have been closing these for a while now, but I notice others don't flag it. I am just wondering if I should adjust my opinion on these.

---

Quoting the [DBA on-topic FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

If you have a question about...

- Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
- Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
- Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity
- Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
- Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap

then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: So you think it is actively off topic for SO? Why? What does it violate in this list? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MartinSmith Well a) it's not about "code", it's about design. The fact that the design is expressed in code is not core to the question. And b) it is expressly [on-topic for dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - point 3 of 5: *Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity*

Comment: The SO FAQ does not say questions have to be about code. Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" (e.g. RDBMSs) are explicitly on topic. Basic questions about first to third normal form don't require a database professional to answer. It should just be answered on SO IMO. No need to migrate.

Comment: I think the database design belongs to SO in the same way as, for example, code architecture design into layers. It is a normal part of many programmers' work.

Comment: @Bohemian, Stackoverflow is for design too. There's no such thing as code without design.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Nope.

[Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) is meant for [database *professionals*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour), not some run-of-the-mill Stack Overflow question on using SQL. More specifically, it says verbatim that basic SQL questions should remain on Stack Overflow. If it's not suitable for Stack Overflow, don't chuck the trash next door! Just vote to close under another (suitable) reason.

While Database Administrators *do* cover database design, that would be for higher-level questions, rather than basic table design questions like these.

Also, see this [DBA meta question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/how-do-we-define-a-question-as-being-too-basic-where-do-we-draw-the-line) on their perspective on beginner questions -- **they don't want them**.

Comment: But point 3 of 5 in the [on-topic FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says: *Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity*. It totally on topic for DBA

Comment: @Bohemian - It is entirely possible for a question to be on topic for more than one site.

Comment: @Bohemian: but they're geared towards database _professionals_, which makes SO better fit than DBA.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Look at at this, too: [Should basic SQL questions be allowed?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/755/should-basic-sql-questions-be-allowed) We don't want them away either!

Comment: @ypercube - But IMO they shouldn't be actively migrated from SO as they are also on topic there. I only vote to migrate ones about administration or that require a more in depth/expert answer than is common on SO.

Comment: OK then. On the basis of *who* asks the question, if the asker is clearly not a DBA, but a regular programmer, then it's on topic for SO.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree on that.